# Convert CSS to HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to convert CSS to HTML. Our company's intranet is set up so that it strips the stylesheet out of the code.

I'd like to be able to use existing web pages that utilize CSS but somehow convert my stylesheet to inline styles. Is this possible?

Thank you,
John

Comment: What kind of intranet is that?

Comment: Is there any explanation as to *why* it's set up to do that?

Comment: Nice intranet. Sounds like my workplace. Good thing I'm leaving in two days.

Comment: Does it strip the stylesheet *before* it gets to the browser, or is this some kind of (enforced) browser setting? If it's the latter then possibly a bookmarklet, Greasemonkey, or User, -Script could maybe help.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search turned up [this](http://www.pelagodesign.com/sidecar/emogrifier/). Will that help? You can either do the conversion one-by-one online or it says "download the PHP source" and I guess from there write an application that will batch convert them.

There are a load more (google "convert css to inline"), but this was the first one I found that wasn't online only.